# C# Replace URL Regex

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am trying to pull a URL out of a string and use it later to create a Hyperlink. I would like to be able to do the following:
- determine if the input string contains a URL
- remove the URL from the input string
- store the extracted URL in a variable for later use

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It should be noted that without a few examples, this task is near impossible.

Comment: I use this tool a LOT in my own code.  I am decent with regular expressions, but being able to test them quickly and efficiently, as well as help with building them, is truly priceless.  If I was somewhat less broke I would gladly donate to this developer.

http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: http://madskristensen.net/post/Resolve-and-shorten-URLs-in-Csharp.aspx nice starting point for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great solution for recognizing URLs in popular formats such as:

- www.google.com
- http://www.google.com
- mailto:somebody@google.com
- somebody@google.com
- www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring

The regular expression used is:

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
```

However, I would recommend you go to http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the to see the working example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace input with your input

```
        string input = string.Empty;
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input,
                      @"/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)/");
        List<string> urlList = (matches.Cast<object>().Select(match => match.ToString())).ToList();
```